# Automapper can not map IEnumerable<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ienumerable, automapper

Thats the exception I get:

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
CompanyViewModel -> Company
Razor.Sample.ViewModels.CompanyViewModel.CompanyViewModel -> Model.Company

Destination path:
CompanyListViewModel.Companies.Companies.Companies0[0]

Source value:
Razor.Sample.ViewModels.CompanyViewModel.CompanyViewModel
```

When I run this code:

```
var companyViewModels = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Company>, IEnumerable<CompanyViewModel>>(companies);
var companyListViewModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CompanyViewModel>, CompanyListViewModel>(companyViewModels);
```

Thats my mapper profile:

```
CreateMap<IEnumerable<CompanyViewModel>, CompanyListViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.TopRankings, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Select(c => c.TopRanking)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.TotalCompaniesWithOpenPositions,
        o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Count(c => c.HasOpenPositions == true)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.TotalEmployees,
        o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Select(c => c.NumberOfEmployees).Sum<int>(s => s)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Companies, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Select(c => c)));
```

I know that the CreateMap should not have the `IEnumerable<T>` **but HOW then can I map from each CompanyViewModel and its properties to create a Sum with LINQ** for example and assign it to the `dest.TotalEmployees`? I need the enumerable in the profile not in the mvc controller where I call the `.Map<T>()`.

Comment: Make `CompanyViewModels` a property of `CompanyListViewModel` and do the aggregations inside the view model, not through AutoMapper.

Comment: I am always thinking should I put those logic inside the ViewModel or Automapper. Doesnt matter in which it makes the other tool/object somehow useless.

Comment: Well, use either tool/object appropriately. AM is perfect for the `Company, CompanyViewModel` mapping. It's not meant for aggregating lists of objects (only *nested* collections, based on some naming conventions).